# Enlarging BoxCollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make enlarging BoxCollider. First I wanted to get a Boxcollider and set the size of it, and then make enlarging (for a specified period of time)

I stopped at setting the size. I do not have any idea how to make it.

I got 3 errors:

> - Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> - Method must have a return type
> - Type expected

code:

```
public class Scaling : MonoBehaviour { 
public float speed = 0.1f; // speed of resizing


BoxCollider myCollider = transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider> (); // get component of box collider
myCollider.size = new Vector3(3,3,3); // resize collider  - problematic line


private Vector3 targetScale = new Vector3(30,1,1); // sarget scale for object

void Start() {}

void Update() {
    transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp (transform.localScale, targetScale, speed * Time.deltaTime); // object resizing
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to create a Vector2 with 3 arguments rather than a Vector3.

```
BoxCollider myCollider = transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();
myCollider.size = new Vector3(3,3,3); // here are these errors
```

Comment: Oh, i did not see this misspell in code, i need to make a break i think. Thanks, but i still have the same errors

Comment: Can you paste the whole code? You might have unclosed braces or something else if it's the same compiler error.

Comment: i will paste it but not today - i turn off my pc today (too much time on the pc for one day), i will do this in 10 hours i think, ok?

Comment: You should not call GetComponent outside of a Unity function - try putting it in your start function, and do the same when setting the size.